# Expression - Build a full Query

Tags: c#, linq, expression

In my project I have a base class to execute read function on database.

All inherited classes will be able to build their own query (where clause, filter, paging, etc). However I don't want to expose anything about IQueryable from my base class.

Is it possibile build a simple query (with where, paging and sorting) from Expression object?
As far as I Know with expression is possible build predicate only.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) what you are looking for?

Comment: Not really..Your link works to build predicate only (where clause), instead I nedd to build IOrderedQueryable, Paging and other stuff from Expression.